# Adding a second 'new' action to a resource's routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, action

I need to add a second 'new' action (called *different_new*) to a resource called *Things*. I would like it to resolve to:

```
things/different_new
```

I have a different_new action defined on my *things_controller.rb*

Following the [rails guide to routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) I see this example for adding a custom action as a route:

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

However any action added like this is added to a specific resource. For example the above would result in a route like this:

photos/:photo_id/preview

SO this will not work for me as I want the action to be where a new resource is created, not an action for a resource that is already created.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to member, there is also a collection option:

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

Or for your case:

```
resources :things do
  collection do
    get 'different_new'
  end
end
```

This is described in section 2.9.2 on the rails routing guide.

Comment: Perfect. I read section 2.9.2 and didn't make the connection at all. Now it has clicked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

New action (in this case your `different_new` action) is not associated with any existing resource, so it should be a collection route:

```
resources :things do
  get :different_new, :on => :collection
end
```

It'll generate a path like `things/different_new`. Though, unlike with predefined `new` action url helper will be plural - `different_new_things_path`.

Comment: This will work as well.  I think the convention is that once you have more than one get route for a collection, you should use the collection do ... end syntax.

Comment: Sure, but in this case there's only one route, so I used `:on => :collection`.

Comment: KL-7, I was just pointing the convention out so if someone later reads this they know which one to do.